# GoogleCharts with php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, charts

Greetings stackoverflow !
I've currently put some hands on charts, specifically google charts and working with php and phpmyadmin, i'm trying to pull results from database (course name + a number for a piechart) using a normal query and a result set, however i'm only getting one row while looping, i'll post my code below in order to get some tips if possible. ( FIXED IT , CHECK FIRST ANSWER )

```
<?php
   include('../session.php');  
include("../config.php");
   ?>

<?php  




$sqlMostTakenCourse="SELECT course_title, count( * )
FROM wp_wpcw_user_courses, wp_wpcw_courses
WHERE wp_wpcw_user_courses.course_id = wp_wpcw_courses.course_id
AND wp_wpcw_user_courses.course_progress >0
AND wp_wpcw_user_courses.user_id
IN (

SELECT wp_users.ID
FROM wp_users, wp_usermeta, jdashboard
WHERE wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'CouponCode'
AND jdashboard.username = 'jad'
AND wp_usermeta.meta_value = jdashboard.coupon
AND wp_usermeta.user_id = wp_users.ID
)
GROUP BY course_title
ORDER BY count( * ) DESC ";



mysqli_set_charset($db,"utf8");

$resultMostTakenCourse = mysqli_query($db, $sqlMostTakenCourse);



   if(mysqli_num_rows($resultMostTakenCourse) > 0){

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultMostTakenCourse)){



  ?>


<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Task', 'Hours per Day' ],

          [   ' <?php   echo $row[0];  ?>', <?php    echo $row[1];      ?>     ],

          ['Sleep',    7]
        ]);
<?php }} ?>
        var options = {
          title: 'My Daily Activities'

        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

`[   ' <?php   echo $row[0];  ?>', <?php    echo $row[1];      ?>     ],`   Is pulling only 1 row from the database, i'll review my code to see what's missing and would appreciate some help and tips.
 EDIT : i realised loop isn't creating ['name',number] depending on rows, will try to work around that

Comment: You should realize that it makes no sense to output a full HTML document inside a loop ... `html`, `head`, `body` must all occur only once, not multiple times.

Comment: Thank you for that, i've taken them out from the loop, but do you have any other idea or tip for the problem ?

Comment: Well you are also _overwriting_ your JS function `drawChart` in each loop iteration ...

Comment: that one opened my eyes to some stuff thank you, i've fixed my prob, i've posted edited code as answer if you'd like to view :)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem using data.addRow() functions and initializing variable before loop , the modified code is as follows :

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Course');
data.addColumn('number', 'Count');

<?php 



        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultMostTakenCourse)){



  ?>


 data.addRow(['<?php echo $row[0]; ?>', <?php echo $row[1]; ?>]);

        <?php } ?>

        var options = {
          title: 'Courses / Registered times'

        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
```